# MySQL slow sending data

Tags: mysql

I have a large table that frequently sends 3,000 rows of data to a client.

The longest wait state is `Sending data`.  I would like to minimize this if possible!

Is there a foolproof way of doing so?

Comment: Please post the query that is taking long to run. Also please tell us if the table/tables involved are MyISAM, InnoDB, or both.

Comment: Also, what is "slow"? 1 second, 10 minutes, a lifetime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Send fewer rows to the client.

Send less data per row to the client.

Compress the data from the server to the client.

Note that there seems to be a raging argument on the web as to the meaning of "Sending data".  Some day that it might actually mean the prior step.